# is this possible use ftpwebrequest to call fileshare

Tags: c#, windows

Am just wondering is this possible to use `FPTwebRequest` to call a file share.

I have this line in my code to call my ftp site

```
  reqFTP = 
     (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + "126.0.0.1" + "/"));
```

but am trying to do like

```
  reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("//126.0.0.1/"));
```

Is this possible or what is the best way to call the fileshare?

Comment: what do you hope to accomplish by removing the `ftp` ??

Comment: BTW - Your slashes are incorrect for accessing a file share they should be back-slashes `\\`.

Comment: why use an FTP request when System.IO should work ?

Comment: @dvhh - It is true that if you only ever need to support file shares that you would only need to implement the file access classes, but if you have a mixed protocol application (which I assume the OP does based on previous questions) it is sometimes valuable to have access to both protocols. I've used it personally in the past, though rarely found use for both protocols simultaneously.

Comment: Please be sure to delete [your duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527430/modify-ftpwebrequest-to-fileshare) today if this is in fact an exact duplicate. In the future (as I believe you've been warned before) **do not double post questions**. That is a good way to get moderators involved.

Comment: Ooops Sorry,i was suppose to delete the previous post and create this post only the "FtpWebRequest.Create". code to easy understand.Anyway thanks for the reminder i will delete it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. File shares use the SMB protocol as opposed to the FTP protocol implemented by `FtpWebRequest`.

These protocols are not interchangeable (and vary in just about every way). If you want your application to support file shares then the standard `FileStream` operations should work (given appropriate permissions and a little variance to allow an explicit user).

Comment: Thanks @M.Bacbcock,i might write another method to look a fileshare to do the same process what my ftp does.is that make sense ?

Comment: Your question was about how to access file shares using `FtpWebRequest`, not how to make them work interchangably. My approach in the past (though may not be absolutely correct) was to try to parse the directory value as a URL, if that didn't work failover to processing to file share logic. You can actually implement both in the same method, but I would probably separate it out for the sake of code clarity and maybe even to allow the possibility of plugin-izing the file access methods. How _you_ do it though is up to you.